# write tkinter box input to excel cell

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Problem statement: user input through tkinter box is not written to excel sheet!

My main issue is with .get() statement. I just want the user input printed over on excel, regardless of input type.

Thanks in advance.

```
from tkinter import *


# define this function to close the window after text submition
def close_window():
    window.destroy()

#window dimentions  
window = Tk()
window.title("My App")
window.geometry('350x200')

v = StringVar()
user_data = Entry(textvariable=v)
user_data.pack() 
ans = v.get()

# I need this input on excel

f= open('sht.csv','w')
f.write(ans)
f.close()


button = Button(text="Submit", command = close_window)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you call the close_window function, try this, I've add the function write_to.
Anyway I suggest an OO approach.

```
from tkinter import *


# define this function to close the window after text submition
def close_window():
    window.destroy()

#window dimentions  
window = Tk()
window.title("My App")
window.geometry('350x200')

v = StringVar()
user_data = Entry(textvariable=v)
user_data.pack() 


# I need this input on excel
def write_to():
    ans = v.get()
    f= open('sht.csv','w')
    print(ans)
    f.write(ans)
    f.close()


button = Button(text="Submit", command = write_to)
button.pack()

window.mainloop()
```